# Find all [x;y] for which: GCD(x,y) + 5 = LCM(x,y)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have two numbers (x and y) both of which are from the **natural numbers**. The task is:

> Find all [x;y] pairs for which:
>
> **GCD(x,y) + 5 = LCM(x,y)**

The result should be:
**{[1;6], [6;1], [2;3], [3;2], [5;10], [10;5]}**

The problem is I have no idea how to get to the result. I got stuck in a loop of statements. So I'll appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the lcm is a multiple of the gcd, hence (as it is different) at least twice as big. This makes the lcm $\le 10$, and leaves only $(1,6), (5,10)$ for $(\gcd,\operatorname{lcm})$

Comment: Took me quite a while to see it but I finalyl got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
 Rewrite $x=md,y=nd$ where $gcd(m,n)=1$ then find that $d|5$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$Since $\gcd(x,y)\mid\gcd(x,y)$ and $\gcd(x,y) \mid \lcm(x,y)$ then we gave 
$$\gcd(x,y)\mid\lcm(x,y)-\gcd(x,y)=5$$.

This shows that $\gcd(x,y) \in \{1,5 \}$.